# What is the most recent Salesforce Mobile iOS Native SDK and when is the next major release due?

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, release

As a developer of Salesforce connected mobile iOS apps I am interested to know what is the most recent release and as importantly when is the next major release due along with the features of that new release. I would like to know when is the next major release planed for Salesforce Mobile SDK iOS Native.

Comment: You know the [SDK is public on Github](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS), right?

Comment: yes I am familiar with the SDK on Github, and forgive my response but your question does not help answer two important parts to my question, namely, when is the next major release due? and what the feature list for the next major release is>

Comment: Would you consider StackExchange more or less likely than a project repo to be able to answer a question about the roadmap of that project? Wouldn't it answer your question about the current release? Have you tried asking there?